# Scope of warnings.simplefilter('error', Image.DecompressionBombWarning)

Tags: python, tornado, python-imaging-library

I have the following skeleton tornado program:

```
class IS(BaseHandler):
   @tornado.gen.coroutine
   def get(self):
      #render stuff

   def post(self):
      try:
      # load Image 
      except RuntimeWarning:
      # handle exception

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
   def __init__(self):
      # Current handlers
      handlers = [
         (r'/',IS),
      ]

      # Settings dict for Application
      settings = {
         "template_path": "templates",
         "static_path": "static"
      }
      tornado.web.Application.__init__(self,handlers,debug=True,**settings)

if __name__ =='__main__':
   # is this the right place to set the warnings?
   warnings.simplefilter('error', Image.DecompressionBombWarning)
   app=Application()
   server=tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
   server.listen(7000)
   tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

I'm wondering what the scope of settings the warnings is? Do I have to set it within the IS class? Or is where I have set it ok? Or should it be within the Application **init**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`warnings.simplefilter` affects the whole process (when it is not called from inside a `with warnings.catch_warnings()` block), so to control warnings globally you just have to call it once at startup, as you've done.

Comment: As always thank you Ben. I owe you so many drinks I've lost count :P